# MPI remote nodes do not execute

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi, snow

I am trying to build a cluster to parallelize a R function. I use Open MPI in Ubuntu and R packages (Rmpi and Snow). The test code I am running is:

```
cl <- makeMPIcluster(8)
fun <- function(){
    Sys.info()[c("nodename")]
}
clusterCall(cl,fun)
stopCluster(cl)
mpi.quit()
```

The command is:

```
mpirun -H localhost,node2 -n 1 R --slave -f testSnowMPI.R
```

The problem is that all the returns are the local hostname. I observed the process in localhost and node2 as well and the process seems to start (4 in localhost and 4 in node2) but quickly the slaves processes at node2 stop and everything is executed in localhost.

I did another test having different scripts (testSnowMPI.R) for each node and when I changed the parameter *-n 1 to -n 2* I had different returns as expected but both scripts were executed by the localhost.

Another interesting test is when I make the *mpirun* command in localhost but I just set node2 host for the execution (*-H node2*). The answer I have is *All nodes which are allocated for this job are already filled.*

I can ping localhost from node2 and node2 from localhost. And I already have set the ssh connection without passphrase.

It seems like the processes in node2 start normally but it can not write the return to the master and then localhost do all the work.

I did the same tests having node2 as the localhost and the behaviour was exactly the same.

Do you have any idea about the weird behaviour of these tests?

EDIT

I did some tests using only Rmpi functions (without Snow functions). I wrote this script:

```
mpi.spawn.Rslaves()
mpi.close.Rslaves()
```

The command was:

```
mpirun -H localhost,node2,node2 -n 1 R --slave -f testSnowMPI.R
```

And I got this output:

```
master (rank 0, comm 1) of size 3 is running on: node1
slave1 (rank 1, comm 1) of size 3 is running on: node1
slave2 (rank 2, comm 1) of size 3 is running on: node1
```

(node1 is the localhost)

Comment: The problem may be related to spawning more workers than the slots that you've requested via the mpirun `-H` option. What happens if you execute mpirun with `-H node2,node2,node2,node2` and use `cl <- makeMPIcluster(mpi.universe.size()-1)` in your R script?

Comment: Hi, @SteveWeston. When I try only `-H node2,node2,node2,node2` I get the same error "All nodes which are allocated for this job are already filled." When I try `-H node2,node2,node2,node2` all the processes are executed by localhost. And when I try `-H node2,localhost,node2,node2`, for example, the master starts in node2 butt all the slaves run in localhost. It seems the slaves can not work remotely and localhost starts executing everything... I have tried a lot of things but I could not get this right yet. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry. The second case is `-H localhost,node2,node2,node2,node2`.

Comment: I edited the question with some tests only with Rmpi functions. The master do not send the jobs to the slaves for some reason.